# What is a regex to capitalize new lines?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the following string, how do I capitalize all of the first characters in each line:

```
"New line\r\n\r\nalso a new line\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nanother new line"
```

I tried something like `gsub(/\\n\w/){ $&.capitalize! }` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex `^[a-z]` or `(?<=^|[\r\n])[a-z]` to select first non-capital character in each line

Comment: Maybe `(?<=^|[\r\n]{1,2})[a-z]` ? (I'm not sure)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV quantifiers like `*`,`+`,`{n}` in **lookbehind** are not supported by ruby

Answer (score 3):

Let's make it trickier by introducing leading spaces:

```
str = "New line\r\n\r\n also a new line\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nanother new line"
str.gsub(/^\s*[a-z]/i){|x| x.upcase}
#=> "New line\r\n\r\n Also a new line\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nAnother new line"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"New line\r\n\r\n also a new line\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nanother new line"
.gsub(/^\W*./, &:upcase)
```